# Adding text container to NSLayoutManager results in exception

Tags: cocoa, swift, nstextview

In my cocoa application (written in Swift), I am trying to make a pagination system, where each page is an instance of CASTextView (a subclass of NSTextView). Additionally, each CASTextView retains an instance of CASTextContainer (a subclass of NSTextContainer). In order to accomplish pagination, I have made all instances of CASTextView share the same NSLayoutManager instance via a singleton pattern.

I have implemented the method `- (void)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)aLayoutManager didCompleteLayoutForTextContainer:(NSTextContainer *)aTextContainer atEnd:(BOOL)flag` as follows:

```
func layoutManager(layoutManager: NSLayoutManager!,
    didCompleteLayoutForTextContainer textContainer: NSTextContainer!,
    atEnd layoutFinishedFlag: Bool)
{
    let containers = layoutManager.textContainers
    if !layoutFinishedFlag || !textContainer {
        let lastContainer = containers[containers.count - 1] as NSTextContainer
        if !textContainer || textContainer == lastContainer {
            if layoutManager.glyphRangeForTextContainer(lastContainer).length > 0 {
                addPage(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to receive the singleton instance of NSLayoutManager (CASTextView.sharedLayoutManager):

```
class var sharedLayoutManager: NSLayoutManager {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = NSLayoutManager()
        }

        return Singleton.instance // All text containers share the same layout manager.
    }
```

The method addPage initializes a text view, replaces the text container with one of type CASTextContainer, and then replaces the layout manager with the shared layout manager, as follows:

```
func addPage(sender: NSNotification?) {
    let midpoint = NSWidth(mainView.frame) / 2
    let firstEndpoint = midpoint - 500
    var rect: NSRect = NSZeroRect
    let yValue: CGFloat = 50 + 1425 * CGFloat(pages.count)
    mainView.frame.size = NSMakeSize(NSWidth(mainView.frame), yValue + 1675) // extend the scrolling size to account for new subview.
    let origin = NSMakePoint(firstEndpoint, yValue)
    let size = NSMakeSize(1000, 1375)
    rect.origin = origin
    rect.size = size
    var nextView = CASTextView(frame: rect)
    var nextContainer = CASTextContainer(containerSize: containerSize)
    nextContainer.mainView = nextView
    nextView.replaceTextContainer(nextContainer)
    nextContainer.replaceLayoutManager(CASTextView.sharedLayoutManager)
    nextView.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewNotSizable
    nextView.delegate = nextView
    nextView.usesFindPanel = true
    mainView.addSubview(nextView)
    pages.append(nextView)
    for var i = 0; i < pages.count - 1; ++i {
        pages[i].nextPage = pages[i + 1] // reset nextPage variable
    }
}
```

Each CASTextView retains a reference to the next page (also of type CASTextView), and the last CASTextView is to have this reference (called nextPage) set to nil. The variable 'pages' is an array of all of the pages retained by the NSLayoutManagerDelegate (a subclass of NSViewController).

**The problem:** The call to addPage is executing exactly when it is intended to (when one page's text container can no longer fit all of the text), but is causing an exception to occur in the following method:

```
 -[NSBigMutableString _getBlockStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:stopAtLineSeparators:]: Range {0, 98} out of bounds; string length 0
```

I cannot find documentation on this method anywhere; the leading underscore seems to imply that it is a private method of NSString, but the stack trace shows that it is being called by `-[NSString paragraphRangeForRange:]` . Interestingly, the stack trace does not show that the addPage method is on the stack. Here is the stack trace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90ef3f1c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff869b274e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90ef3dcd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d480b5c -[NSString _getBlockStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:stopAtLineSeparators:] + 239
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d4a699c -[NSString paragraphRangeForRange:] + 57
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea8a7fe -[NSTextView _markTextEditedForRange:] + 1405
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea852a0 -[NSTextView insertText:replacementRange:] + 2800
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8eaba451 -[NSTextView insertText:] + 318
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8eade292 -[NSTextView(NSKeyBindingCommands) insertNewline:] + 239
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea8f544 -[NSTextView doCommandBySelector:] + 195
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b6a71 -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) doCommandBySelector:completionHandler:] + 118
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea64c9b -[NSKeyBindingManager(NSKeyBindingManager_MultiClients) interpretEventAsCommand:forClient:] + 1899
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b54a2 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke968 + 335
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b6edf -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) hasMarkedTextWithCompletionHandler:] + 76
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b52c3 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 95
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b45d8 -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 101
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b5234 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke956 + 321
    17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0e204f __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_5 + 70
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0ae056 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke174 + 2387
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b6edf -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) hasMarkedTextWithCompletionHandler:] + 76
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0ad674 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 95
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0ab3c8 -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 101
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0ad3d0 -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:] + 3293
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea8410e _NSTSMEventHandler + 324
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8decd6c8 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1128
    25  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8deccb8e _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 386
    26  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8decca02 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 43
    27  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0db37c SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 417
    28  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0db87c __SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 400
    29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0dbb36 __SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 189
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0db3d0 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 501
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0db6bf SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 236
    32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0d8a31 SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler + 295
    33  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0dd329 __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 296
    34  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0dd1f8 __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 437
    35  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0d84ad TSMKeyEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 701
    36  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0e1fd0 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_4 + 251
    37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0e1ec6 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_3 + 330
    38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0e1d02 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 259
    39  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0e1b85 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 251
    40  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e0e198f TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler + 3068
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b5046 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke945 + 131
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b4502 -[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 127
    43  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0b4b35 -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:] + 1266
    44  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea8394e -[NSTextInputContext handleEvent:] + 109
    45  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea63368 -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:] + 207
    46  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea837cd -[NSTextView keyDown:] + 695
    47  AppKit                              0x00007fff8efa2d7b -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] + 1959
    48  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea337bc -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 368
    49  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e9e5dc0 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4008
    50  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e871b48 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    51  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e85d2de NSApplicationMain + 1778
    52  Application                           0x000000010000e2a5 top_level_code + 37
    53  Application                         0x000000010000e2da main + 42
    54  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9422d5c9 start + 1
    55  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was occurring as a result of my call to `replaceLayoutManager`. I altered the way that I initialize the text view. Rather than using the `init(frame: frameRect)` constructor, I utilized the designated initializer by separately initializing a text container as such:

```
var nextContainer = CASTextContainer(containerSize: containerSize)
var nextView = CASTextView(frame: rect, textContainer: nextContainer)
```

I then proceeded to call `mainView.addSubview(nextView)`, and **after the subview was added**, I called the following:

```
CASTextView.sharedLayoutManager.addTextContainer(nextContainer)
```

which then allowed for the pagination effect to take place.